# SharePoint List Permissions - Edit Items = Edit Pages

Tags: 2007, permissions

I have a serious problem. When I give a visitors group edit permissions on a list, they have permission to edit all pages associated with that list, such as adding/removing web parts from the views. I need them to be able to add and edit items in the list but I also need them not to be able to permanently break the list by doing something like deleting the web part from editform.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom permission level that is a copy of the Read permission group. Alter this copy by ticking the Add Items option. Then give the Visitor group this permission level. It will allow them to read all content and add items to the lists, but not edit or delete anything.

Comment: At that level they can add items (and I'm guessing aspx pages) but can't edit. They need edit too. If they create an item that says "SharePoint blows" they need to be able to go back and add "hard", for instance. Otherwise we're looking at requiring them to email the admin to say "I said 'SharePoint blows' but I meant 'SharePoint blows hard'" and then the admin has to go in and type "SharePoint blows hard" and it's just a lot of work to specify exactly how much SharePoint blows

Comment: I think I know a good user name. How do I change it

Comment: Then you can add in edit as well, you can also remove any personalization options too.

Comment: They can edit *pages* in edit. Is the issue